# Get Record From Combo box in gridview in C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

hi i have gridview with three columns Product Name,unit,rate.... product Name have combo box what i want when i select product from combo box it will select unit and rate from database and display into unit and rate column   for example if i select product Rice it select unit=kg and rate=100 from database please guide me how to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you have a GridView like below :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Test1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Test2</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

you can use your controls like this :

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control cont = (Control)sender;

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(cont).NamingContainer;
    int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

    DropDownList dropdown = (DropDownList)row.Cells[0].FindControl("DropDownList1");
    ///now you have dropdownlist.seletedvalue

    TextBox text1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox1");
    ///now you have textbox1.text

    TextBox text2 = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox2");
    ///now you have textbox2.text
}
```